# local approximation by smooth functions

Tags: proof-explanation, sobolev-spaces

[image]

Can someone explain to me where the yellow one comes from...

thank you

Comment: Is it clear to you that in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $\phi \in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}^n), \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \phi(x)dx = 1$, $\phi_\epsilon(x) = \epsilon^{-n}\phi( x/\epsilon)$ then $u \ast \phi_\epsilon$ is a $C^\infty$ approximation of $u$, which is also an approximation of all the derivatives, because $D^\alpha (u \ast \phi_\epsilon )= (D^\alpha u) \ast \phi_\epsilon $. The purpose of your theorem is to show the approximation of $u$ and all  its derivatives is in the uniform norm as well as in any $L^p $ norm.

Comment: @reuns..how the later terms comes

Comment: @reuns..the yellow marks of 2 and 3 and 4

Comment: what do you not understand in what I wrote

Comment: @reuns..sorry but no im slow learner

Comment: @InverseProblem You have highlighted a whole bunch of equalities : there are like four $=$ signs in the first highlighted statement. Please focus on one at a time. For example, do you understand why $D^\alpha u_\epsilon(x) = D^\alpha(u * \phi_\epsilon(x))$? This is the definition of $u_{\epsilon}$, if you look in the notes. Now, if this was not confusing you should not have highlighted it. Pick one confusing statement at a time, and I will clarify it for you.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг..this one $D^\alpha u_\epsilon(x) = D^\alpha(u * \phi_\epsilon(x))$ is theorem  and i understand that from that i am not understand

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг..from second to third it is definition of mollifiers ..but how comes $D^{\alpha}_x$ in 2 highlighted...and then in third highlighted 3 how comes $D^{\alpha}_y$